# Fuzzy Matching player names in R

Tags: r, substring, fuzzyjoin, name-matching

In R, I have two dataframes, one with full names and one with abbreviated names, I want to dplyr join them to see which one has a flag.

However, it is very hard to get matched names, even when I match last names, there are same last names. I'm giving part of the data as example below. Is there anyway I can efficiently and correctly join these two dataframe without any mismatches?

data_1 like:

| Player | Flag |
| --- | --- |
| W. Fofana | 1 |
| N'Golo Kante | 1 |
| Frank Anguissa | 1 |

data_2 like:

| Player |
| --- |
| David Datro Fofana |
| Wesley Fofana |
| N'Golo Kante |
| Andre-Frank Zambo Anguissa |

I tried Last name matching:

```
data_1 <- data_1 %>%
  mutate(player = sub('.*\\s', '', player)) 

data_2 <- data_2 %>%
  mutate(player = sub('.*\\s', '', player))
```

This can match "Andre-Frank Zambo Anguissa" to "Frank Anguissa", but will mismatch W. Fofana and David Datro Fofana.

But if I consider first name, I don't know how to keep cases like "Andre-Frank Zambo Anguissa" and "Frank Anguissa" matched. As that is a quite unique last name, by matching last name I actually can get correct match for it, if involve first name in, I don't think it will work. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot

I tried `fuzzyjoin` too, but it's hard to choose a `max_dist` that allows all correct match/join.

Comment: One possible approach could be to do a `left_join` using the last name (after separating it into its own column in each table), and then pick a distance algorithm to sort within last-name matches for the best candidate.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.